# Calculating magnitude of longitudinal and latitudinal error

Tags: r

Lets say i have those coordinates..

```
   Long.GPS     Lat.GPS     Long.TEST   Lat.TEST
   22.355951    44.699745   24.00092    44.37806
   22.355951    44.699745   24.08816    44.36839
   22.355951    44.699745   23.73256    44.42112
   22.355951    44.699745   22.35929    44.6953
```

Now, what i want is to know how to calculate the magnitude of longitudinal and latitudinal error by the following: **Long.error = |Long.GPS - Long.Test|** 
and the same for latitude.
Then, i would like to know how to calculate the magnitude of total horizontal error as the Euclidean distance from the true location(GPS) to tested location(TEST) by the following: **Total.error = sqrt(Long.error^2 + Lat.error^2)**

After all this, i would like to plot them using ggplot2 geom_point, but i think that i can handle this on my own.

I am quite new into this field and i need help in order to finish my project.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have the formulae you need to apply, what's preventing your from using them? e.g. `df$Long.error <- abs(df$Long.GPS - df$Long.TEST)` ?

Comment: I just did not know how to do it in R, I'm new to this and I did not know if there are any specific scripts, I tried a lot, believe me. Thanks a lot for the point man.

Comment: People who provide answers on StackOverflow are more likely to help if you demonstrate what you've already tried, and show why it didn't work. They're less likely to respond if you ask for homework help (or 'finish my project') without showing any working, as it looks like you're just asking for someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: Well, i'll keep that in mind next time i ask for something, thanks for help anyway. Maybe i didn't explained well, because i'm awake for 20 hours and i just lost my patience with this project..
But no problem, thank you, i'll take it as a constructive critic..
My brain just didn't think about having the resolve right under my nose..

Comment: yes please do; no malice intended. If you're still struggling after applying my suggestion, feel free to update your question with more detail of your attempts.